# How to extract multiple tag values from XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I would like to know how to extract multiple values from a single XML row, the problem is that this XML value somethimes have duplicate (name, id, email) tag childs,
for example:

```xml
<foo>
    <name>
        Dacely Lara Camilo
    </name>
    <id>
        001-1942098-2
    </id>
    <email>
        myuncletouchme@gmail.com
    </email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>
        Alba Elvira Castro
    </name>
    <id>
        001-0327959-2
    </id>
    <email>
        4doorsmorehorse@hotmail.com
    </email>
</foo>
```

Or somethimes the data in that column can be like this

```
<foo>
    <name>
        Nelson Antonio Jimenez
    </name>
    <id>
        001-0329459-3
    </id>
    <email>
        gsucastillo@tem.com
    </email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>
        Emelinda Serrano
    </name>
    <id>
        001-0261732-4
    </id>
    <email>
        gucastillo@tem.com
    </email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>
        Nelson Antonio Jimenez
    </name>
    <id>
        001-0329259-3
    </id>
    <email>
        gucastillo@tem.com
    </email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>
        Emelinda Serrano
    </name>
    <id>
        001-0268332-4
    </id>
    <email>
        gucastillo@tem.com
    </email>
</foo>
```

And I want all of then to be transpose to a single row just like this:

[image]

My current code just extract the first pair, if it can help,

```sql
WITH BASEDATA (ID, SIGNATURE, X) AS (
    SELECT TOP 50
        A.ID_SIGNATURE,
        A.SIGNATURE,
        A.XML
    FROM DWH.DIM_CORE_SIGNATURE A
)SELECT
    ID,
    A.value('(id)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ID_SIGNATURE,
    A.value('(name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS NAME,
    A.value('(email)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS EMAIL
FROM BASEDATA
CROSS APPLY X.nodes('//foo') AS SIGNATURE(A)
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Your SQL appears to work fine, I don't follow the problem. [db<>fiddle]((https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5407eb04962fdaab69912f616a62f93d) (Though I recommend that you choose a better data type than one than allows to 1 billion characters...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notable points:

- `.nodes('/foo')` method has a better, more performant XPath expression.
- It is better to use `.value('(id/text())[1]',...` for the same
  reason.
- As @Lamu already suggested, it is better to use real data types instead of `nvarchar(max)` across the board.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<foo>
    <name>Dacely Lara Camilo</name>
    <id>001-1942098-2</id>
    <email>myuncletouchme@gmail.com</email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>Alba Elvira Castro</name>
    <id>001-0327959-2</id>
    <email>4doorsmorehorse@hotmail.com</email>
</foo>')
, (N'<foo>
    <name>Nelson Antonio Jimenez</name>
    <id>001-0329459-3</id>
    <email>gsucastillo@tem.com</email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>Emelinda Serrano</name>
    <id>001-0261732-4</id>
    <email>gucastillo@tem.com</email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>Nelson Antonio Jimenez</name>
    <id>001-0329259-3</id>
    <email>gucastillo@tem.com</email>
</foo>
<foo>
    <name>Emelinda Serrano</name>
    <id>001-0268332-4</id>
    <email>gucastillo@tem.com</email>
</foo>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID,
    c.value('(id/text())[1]', 'char(13)') AS ID_SIGNATURE,
    c.value('(name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(30)') AS NAME,
    c.value('(email/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') AS EMAIL
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/foo') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| ID | ID_SIGNATURE  |         NAME         |            EMAIL            |
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | 001-1942098-2 | Dacely Lara Camilo   | myuncletouchme@gmail.com    |
|  1 | 001-0327959-2 | Alba Elvira Castro   | 4doorsmorehorse@hotmail.com |
|  2 | 001-0329459-3 | Nelson Antonio Jimen | gsucastillo@tem.com         |
|  2 | 001-0261732-4 | Emelinda Serrano     | gucastillo@tem.com          |
|  2 | 001-0329259-3 | Nelson Antonio Jimen | gucastillo@tem.com          |
|  2 | 001-0268332-4 | Emelinda Serrano     | gucastillo@tem.com          |
+----+---------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
```